# How to get return value of multiple async calls when it is all done?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using 3rd party api method that is async. I have list of items that need to be passed onto this async method and I would like to print out results of all returning results once all async calls are completed. I know I can use callback to accomplish this. But I cannot get it to work. It prints nothing. Obviously I am using callback wrong here. Yes I read about callback here : https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks. Has good examples. But not sure how to make it work with array of async calls and combining the results.

```
var resultArray = [];
var items = ["one", "two", "three"];
getResult(items, printResult);
function printResult()
{
  for(let j=0; j < resultArray.length; j++)
  {
      console.log(resultArray[j]);
  }
}
function getResult(items, callback)
{
 for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++)
 {
  apiClient.findItem(items[i], function (error, item){
  resultArray.push(item.key);
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @JeffreyAGochin pointed out, you can substitute this with promises. If you don't want to do that and you want to stick with callbacks (which I would not recommend), you can use the excellent [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

```
function getResult(item, done) {
  apiClient.findItem(item, done);
}

async.each(items, getResult, function (error, results) {
  // if error is null, then all of your results are in 'results'
  if(error !== null) throw error;
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Example promise implementation (I'm assuming you're using ES6 and thus have Promise natively due to your `let`)

```
// When you are using promises natively (apparently these have performance implications, see comments) your code looks like this:

function getResult(item) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    apiClient.findItem(item, function(error, foundItem) {
      if(error) return reject(error);    
      resolve(foundItem);
    });
  });
}

// If you use the excellent bluebird library though (which is pretty common actually), it looks more like this.
let apiClient = Bluebird.promisifyAll(apiClient);
function getResult(item) { return apiClient.getItemAsync(item); }

var resultsPromise = Promise.all(items.map(getResult));
resultsPromise.then(function(results) {
  results.forEach(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

As for the reason why so many people are suggesting promises; it's because they compose far, far better. Also there are some great libraries that support promises such as [highland](http://highlandjs.org) (which is also by the same author as `async` above) which treats a promise as a first class value. It's hard to treat callbacks like this because there's no real way to 'pass them around'

Comment: Even if promises are available natively, you should use a library, aka [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). Native promises are still very slow.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned bluebird with the promisification. I didn't realize the native promises were slow, however.

Comment: You don't need that `new Promise` wrapper if you've promisified `apiClient`; `getResult` can just be `return apiClient.findItemAsync(item);`

Comment: Which is why the comment says `// with Bluebird this turns into just`. I tried to put both the Bluebird and the non-promisified example into one example. My mistake. I'll separate them out now.

Comment: :Facepalm: sorry, missed that.

Comment: Alternatively OP could even use generators :^) but I won't mention those because that requires even more third party libraries (`co` + `Bluebird`) and isn't supported without flags in Node yet

Comment: I am hearing observable in rx.js is more suited for array of async response than promise since promise is for once single call. Sure you can make promise to do what observable can do. Am I correct that observable is better suited for this?

Comment: `rx.js` is great if you're working on individual sequences of items. I personally prefer `highlandjs`. I don't really like how `rx.js` handles. You could really use any abstraction - rx uses closures and highland uses streams/promises. I prefer the lighter-weight promises and highland so I use that.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for promises. Another option preferred by some is the `async` module:

```
var async = require('async');

async.each(
  items, 
  function (item, cb) { apiClient.findItem(item, cb); },
  function (err, resultArray) {
    for (let j=0; j < resultArray.length; j++) {
      console.log(resultArray[j]);
    }        
  }
);
```

Comment: dammit I got sniped by 30 seconds!

Comment: `function (item, cb) { apiClient.findItem(item, cb); },` is redundant

Comment: Not really. If you pass `apiClient.findItem`, that will be invoked without `apiClient` as `this`. One alternative that would work is `apiClient.findItem.bind(apiClient)`, which is essentially the same as an inline function.

Comment: you lose the function name with bind, imo `function getResult(item, cb) {}` is the way to go if you ever want to make your stack traces look sane

Comment: Way prefer async over promises for this kind of thing. Just seems a lot clearer, what's going on. But that's all personal preference.

Comment: How does async.each know that item is an element of items array? Does it take array as first parameter and use item variable represents items array element in each iteration? Like foreach(var item in items) in c#

Comment: I am not exactly seeing how resultArray is being populated from apiClient.findItem response. It is being printed but nowhere in there it is actually being populated by the results of my async apiClient call. If you see my code above it is doing apiClient.findItem(items[i], function (error, item){
  resultArray.push(item.key);
  });

Comment: The results from the first callback function are all collected into the final `resultArray` passed to the second callback function. The first function is the *iterator* callback, the second the *completed* callback.

Comment: how does it know it the result is item.key for example. It cannot just automatically grab any result. Cuz findItem is not returning any value. It does provide callback function as a parameter to access item.key.

Comment: Whatever `apiClient.findItem` calls `cb` with as a result is what's used, assuming it calls cb with the usual `(err, result)` pattern. With `async.each`, the results array items will be in the same order as the `items` array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82755/discussion-between-doodlekana-and-jacob).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Promises library to manage all of the async requests.  They typically have a all method, that waits for all promises to complete.  You can wrap the other async library call in the promises.

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 0):

In `getResult` you're not calling the `callback` parameter, so it will definitely not print anything in that case.

If you're sticking to callbacks instead of promises, which is fully acceptable despite the raging opinion-wars, a nice npm package is [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async). Check out the `each` function in that library, it will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://howtonode.org/promises.

I suggest you use a variable to count the requests done, so you can check when all the them are finished and do what you need with the array.

Comment: That exact article points out the existence of `Q.all()` which renders the destructive assignment (keeping track of how many have 'finished') pointless. It's also a bit out of date ;-)